# Pop-up modal with php function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new to modal show-up bootstrap. please someone help me.. my problem is how to fetch my table data's dynamically and display it to the modal content when the button modal click.. I tried searching but i can't get on how to do it perfectly..

my code is below:

Please someone help me... What should I use??

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="../js/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="../js/js/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" >

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
$("#btnShow").click(function(){
$('#demoModal').modal('show');
});
});
</script>
```

```html
<div>
<button id="btnShow">Chapter</div>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="demoModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">

<h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Chapter List</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">


<!-- the possible data that should be fetch -->

  <?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","scenezone");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$sql = "SELECT chapter_title FROM story_chapter
WHERE story IN (SELECT story FROM story_chapter WHERE status = '1');";

$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);

// Fetch all
$i = 0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
if ($i % 5 == 0) {
echo "<tr>";
}
echo "<td><p>".$row["Chapter"]."</p>
</td>";
if ($i % 5 == 4) {
echo "</tr>";
}
$i++;
}
// Free result set
mysqli_free_result($result);

mysqli_close($con);
?>

</div>
```

Comment: do select the answer if it helped you so other having the same problem also get the benefit

Comment: thank you for the answer.. it help me..

Comment: you are welcome, please can you select the answer as the correct one? so that it might help others who are looking for the same solution. just click on the Grey tick mark sign ✓ on my answer under vote up .

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are working on a very basic level with simple `php` files in work. The data that you need to show should be in a `.php` file lets say `chapters.php`, and you should call that file using `ajax` when the `bootstrap` modal is shown by `clicking` a button.

I assume you have the default `html` structure for the bootstrap modal with the `modal-body` class for the body section.

Now bootstrap modal have events that can be used for this purpose you can use

`bs.shown.modal` **fired just before the modal is open.**

Bind the event like below

```
  $('#demoModal').on('show.bs.modal', function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'chapters.php',
      method: 'get',
      success: function(data) {
        $(".modal-body").html(data);
      },
      error:function(xhr,code,text){
        alert("error occoured : "+text);
      }
    });
 });
```